# Fecha Sql Server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un campo en mi tabla de tipo varchar el cual tiene datos de fechas “Nov 30 del 2018” algo así, cuando realizo el select lo convierto con convert(varchar,campo,103) Fecha y todo bien. El problema radica cuando intento hacer un where a ese campo colocando rango de fechas me manda error por intentar convertir un varchar a datetime. Si alguien tiene una idea considerando la data que tengo en esa tabla por favor ayudarme.

Gracias.

[image: Registro de ese campo]

Comment: ¿Sabes cuál ISO de fecha se ha utilizado para guardar fechas como texto?

Comment: Lamentablemente una cadena del tipo `Nov 30 del 2018` no puede convertirse a un `date` con un simple `CONVERT`, habría que procesar la cadena e ir extrayendo los datos de interés. Te sugiero que agregues casos representativos o la descripción del patrón que se usa.

Comment: Comparte un [mcve]. Incluye definición de la tabla, datos de ejemplo y la consulta que estás usando.

Comment: Sea como sea, deberías pensar en normalizar esa situación, creando una columna del tipo `DATETIME` e irla actualizando con los datos de la columna `VARCHAR`. Puedes usar una función de conversión que devuelva `NULL` en caso de fecha errónea y luego revisarías en la nueva columna qué datos quedaron `NULL` para corregirlos *a mano*, no queda otra. No dejes que la tabla siga creciendo con esa anomalía, que podría terminar siendo una gran piedra en el zapato (si ya no lo es). Antes de modificar cualquier cosa, haz copia de seguridad de la BD.

Comment: Esa la tabla la vienen trabajando así por años, recién cayo el caso y no se como proceder. No puedo cambiar la estructura de ese tabla por ahora y la idea es darle una solución.

Comment: Que version de SQL server estás utilizando? si ocupas SQL server 2016 en adelante tienes funciones que te permiten generar objetos de tipo datetime y usarlos en tu query de forma que no tengas que andar haciendo conversiones de string a fecha

Comment: La versión de Sql server que usamos es 2088 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente la solución pasa por "procesar" cualquier patrón de fechas que tengas y normalizar los datos en un formato que pueda ser convertible a una fecha. Hasta los ejemplos que has compartido, podríamos decir que los datos vienen en la forma de: `<nombre mes en español de 3 caracteres> <día como entero> <año tipo YYYY> <HH:MM(AM/PM)>`. Si ese fuera el patrón en todas las filas podríamos aplicar el siguiente criterio para extraer los datos:

- **Mes**: Son tres caracteres, pero el problema es que hay que tener una tabla de conversión de esas cadenas en el número de mes correcto
- **Día**: Es más simple, pero hay que hacer un "padding" con ceros
- **Año**: Este dato viene fácil, son los 4 caracteres correspondientes a la centuria.

---

Hay varias formas de "separar" cada parte de la cadena, voy a la forma más sencilla (aunque algo "extraña") que es la función `PARSENAME()` que  esta pensada para separar las partes de una dirección IP, pero que nos sirve en este caso si convertimos los espacios en puntos. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
create table datos (
  fecha varchar(100)
)

insert into datos(fecha) 
values ('Nov 30 2018 6:40PM'), ('Dic 1 2017 7:10PM')
```

La consulta sería:

```
SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR,PARSENAME(REPLACE(d.fecha,' ','.'),2)) Y,
        m.M,
        RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR,100+PARSENAME(REPLACE(d.fecha,' ','.'),3)),2) D
        FROM datos d
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT '01' M, 'Ene' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '02' M, 'Feb' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '03' M, 'Mar' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '04' M, 'Abr' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '05' M, 'May' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '06' M, 'Jun' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '07' M, 'Jul' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '08' M, 'Ago' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '09' M, 'Sep' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '10' M, 'Oct' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '11' M, 'Nov' NM UNION 
                    SELECT '12' M, 'Dic' NM
                   ) m
                   ON m.NM = PARSENAME(REPLACE(d.fecha,' ','.'),4)
```

Finalmente el resultado:

```
|    Y |  M |  D |
|------|----|----|
| 2018 | 11 | 30 |
| 2017 | 12 | 01 |
```

Lo único que restaría es concatenar las tres columnas, respetando el formato `ISO`: `YYYMMDD` y ahora sí convertir a un `date` o un `datetime` mediante la función `CONVERT()`

Answer (score 0):

El problema es porque varchar no permite que uses un rango de fechas en un WHERE. Para eso puedes dejarlo en formato fecha o bien convertirlo en int con el formato yyyymmdd.

Para esto puedes usar `CONVERT(varchar(8), campo_fecha, 112)`

Comment: me puedes indicar como haría eso?

Comment: Intente esto:      select top 10 
                          cast(convert(varchar(25),cast(convert(char(20), fecha, 103) 
                          as datetime),112)as int)Fecha
                         from LogCorreo
                         where 
                         cast(convert(varchar(25),cast(convert(char(20),fecha,103) as 
                          datetime),112)as int) = 20181130 pero no funciona.

Comment: Edite mi respuesta, verifica eso.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, recuerda revisar [answer]. saludos.

Comment: @Rodrigo Mendoza lamentablemente no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Si estás ocupando SQL Server 2015 en adelante te sugiero hagas lo siguiente:

```
select * from tabla where convert(datetime,campo) >= @fecha1 and convert(datetime,campo)<= @fecha2
```

Ahora bien, si lo que te está llegando en @fecha1 y @fecha2 no son fechas, son strings en formato de fecha puedes tambien usar lo mismo

```
 select * from tabla where convert(datetime,campo) >= convert(datetime,@fecha1) and convert(datetime,campo)<= convert(datetime,@fecha2)
```

En dado caso que no tengan el formato correcto y tengas manera de recibir los datos separados por dia, mes y año, entonces te sugiero que uses la función propia de SQL que te permite generar las fechas teniendo el dia, mes y año

```
select * from tabla where convert(datetime,campo) >= datefromparts(año,mes,dia) and convert(datetime,campo)<= datefromparts(año2,mes2,dia2)
```

Espero te sea de utilidad